# Node.js + Express 3 + Frameset navagation bar

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to use frameset to create a left navigation bar but it doesn't seem to work. My code is

```
<frameset cols="175,*" frameborder="0" frameborder="no" framespacing="0" border="0">
    <frame src="navbar.htm" name="choices" scrolling="auto">
    <frame src="main.htm" name="khephra">
</frameset>
```

Both navbar.htm and main.htm are in the same folder as the ejs. I have tried copying ejs to public folder, still does not work. Any idea?

Update:

From this link I found out that frameset is not supported in node.js. I will try to use iframe

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/zombie-js/nxScI6rvtgA/tpz7Z6myOm4J

Comment: Post some server side code snippets. Did you configure the static middleware?

Comment: I am new to node.js and I arem not even sure how to configure the static middleware. My server side configuration is pretty much the default express configuration with .ejs

Comment: @AlexWu the link you posted is referring to lack of support for frames in *zombie.js*, not node.js.  node.js does not care if your request is coming from a frame.  Please explain what you mean by "doesn't seem to work", and post your server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I just threw together a dead simple express app using your markup and it runs fine with no issue.

I replaced jade with ejs (in package.json and app.js), and added your markup as `views/index.ejs`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html>
  <frameset cols="175,*" frameborder="0" frameborder="no" framespacing="0" border="0">
    <frame src="navbar.htm" name="choices" scrolling="auto">
    <frame src="main.htm" name="khephra">
  </frameset>
</html>
```

I then made two dummy versions of `navbar.htm` and `main.html` and dropped them into `public`.  The final file structure as follows:

```
approot/
  views/
    index.ejs
  public/
    main.htm
    index.htm
```